# Can iTunes Connect Support URL be a simple Tumblr Blog?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm sorry if the answer to this is one google search away -- I couldn't find it.

I don't have the desire or time to build out a web site for the iOS app I'm about to submit.  Does anyone know if Apple will accept a simple Tumblr Blog (`<myappname>.tumblr.com`) devoted to my app?

Comment: I believe it can be an e-mail. Its been a while for me though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the key point:

> Your Support URL must lead to actual contact information for support so
>   that your customers can contact you regarding app issues, general
>   feedback, or feature enhancement requests.

So make sure that your link contains this info.